# Save Dropdownlist value to database

Tags: asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, dropdown, html-select

I have a table with two columns containing dropdownlist, the second dropdownlist is populated based on the first dropdownlist selected value. Now i want to save the second dropdpwnlist selected value to database, this is the code i used:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    List<Category> categories = _dbcontext.Category.ToList();
    ViewBag.ListCategories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");            
    Invoice invoice= new Invoice();
    invoice.StockItems.Add(new StockItems() { StockItemsId = 1});
    return View(decharge);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Invoice invoice)
{
   if (invoice!= null)
   {
        _dbcontext.Invoice.Add(invoice);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetStockByCat(int CatId)
{
    List<Stock> stocks = new List<Stock>();
    stocks = _dbcontext.Stock.Where(s => s.CategoryId == CatId).ToList();
    SelectList stocksList = new SelectList(stocks, "StockId", "Name");
    return Json(stocksList);
}
```

Create View:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.StockItems.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.ListCategories, null, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetStocks(this)" })</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StockItems[i].StockId,null, "--Select --",  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id= "stocks", @name = "stocks"} })</td>

        </tr>
     }
    </tbody>
</table>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetStocks(dropdown1) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        var dropdown2 = $(dropdown1).closest('tr').find('#stocks');
        dropdown2.html(procemessage).show();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetStockByCat", "Stock")';
    
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { CatId: dropdown1.value},
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>---------</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += '<option value="' + data[x].value + '">' + data[x].text + '</option>';
                }
                dropdown2.html(markup).show();
                
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });        
    }
```

When i access to Create View i got this error message:

> InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type
> 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'StockItems[0].StockId'

S how to save the value of the populated dropdownlist to the database??

Comment: Looks like the mother element does not have a child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second Dropdownlist is completed by splicing html with JavaScript, it is not appropriate to use `DropDownListFor` here.

Your `Invoice` model should contain a `List<StockItems>` property like this:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public List<StockItems> StockItems { get; set; }
}
public class StockItems
{ 
    public int StockItemsId { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
}
```

What you want to do should be to pass the value selected in the second Dropdownlist into the `StockItems.StockId`  in the `Invoice`, right?

The easiest way is to use the `select` tag and set the matching `name` attribute(`StockItems[@i].StockId`):

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @*....*@
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.StockItems.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewBag.ListCategories, null, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "GetStocks(this)" })</td>
                <td><select id="stocks" name="StockItems[@i].StockId" class="form-control"></select></td>
            </tr>
         }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Test Result:
[image]